# Any way to change the 'Open in {AppName}' verbiage for deep links?

Tags: ios

I don't think there is a way, but thought it might be a good idea to ask anyways. Is there any way to change the verbiage of the popup that fires when a deep link is triggered?

Currently it says `Open in {AppName}`. I was hoping to either do away with the popup, or change the verbiage somehow.

Here's an example of what I am referring to:

[image]

The url is simple just looks like this: `newser://authorization?{query params}`

Comment: it is depent on your URL schema

Comment: Are you implying there's a way to form the verbiage via URL schema? Or what's the relevance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a url scheme to launch this app. If the app is yours as well as the website, you may want to look into implementing universal links (for iOS 9+) which will allow you to deep link into the app without a popup.

Checkout: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: Seems to only wortk though if you have a HTTPS server. But accept the answer since it does technically answer it. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, yeah you do need a https server, which I would highly recommend updating to if you can. However if this is not possible, you could integrate a service like branch.io who handle the server side part of it for you, you just need to integrate their sdk in the app, fill in the setting in the admin portal, and then it will let you generate universal links.

Comment: yeah we <i>need</i> to yet management doesn't delegate time to do it lol. And, I'll look into branch, sounds promising. Thanks.

Comment: Sweet. Haha yeah, I know the feeling . Have been using branch for years, it's a great solution for deep links, it handles intelligently directing to a website/installed app/appstore depending on the device state too for marketing links 